# Tinymce v6 dropzone config options

Tags: file, upload, tinymce, dropzone

I've created a custom dialog with a dropzone in order to upload files and images to our server. By default the dropzone renders with 'Drop an image here' / 'Browse for an image'.

As part of the tinymce editor options file_picker_type allows setting of the default dropzone and I wondered how to access these options for a stand-alone dropzone?

My tinymce options include:

```
tinymce.init({
  file_picker_types: 'file image'
});
```

My upload dialog config looks something like this:

```
const upload_config = {
    title: 'Upload files',
    size: 'medium',
    body: {
        type: 'panel',
            {
                type: 'dropzone',
                name: 'file_drop',
                types: 'file image' //// <----- something like this???
            }
        ]
    },
    buttons: [
        {
            type: 'cancel',
            name: 'closeButton',
            text: 'Cancel',
        },
        {
            type: 'submit',
            name: 'submitButton',
            text: 'Upload',
            buttonType: 'primary'
        }
    ],
    onSubmit: (api) => {
        // handle upload here
    }
};
```

Anybody managed to fathom this? The tinymce docs are in no way comprehensive as they simply say "A dropzone is a composite component that catches drag and drops items or lets the user browse that can send a list of files for processing and receive the result." but give no details on how to actually do that with a stand alone dropzone.

I've managed to make it all work, but this is the last hurdle.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to override the default image/file upload dialog with the custom one? I'm asking because I see the `file_picker_types` config option. To do so, you will need to use the [file_picker_callback](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/image/#file_picker_callback).

If it's something else and you are not trying to override the default dialog, use [this interactive example](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dialog-examples/#basic-interactive-dialog) as a base. You will need to:

a) Register the custom button with a setup function:

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.ui.registry.addButton('custom-upload', {
      icon: 'upload',
      onAction: function () {
        editor.windowManager.open(upload_config)
      }
    })
  },
```

b) Add this button to the toolbar via `toolbar: 'custom-upload'`. This way, pressing the button will open the dialog based on the `upload_config` variable.

c) You've made a mistake in the panel config. I guess, you forgot to create the `items` array at the beginning. Instead of

```
type: 'panel',
            {
                type: 'dropzone',
                name: 'file_drop',
                types: 'file image' //// <----- something like this???
            }
        ]
```

There should be:

```
type: 'panel',
        items: [
            {
                type: 'dropzone',
                name: 'file_drop',
                label: 'Dropzone',
            }
        ]
```

I've created this fiddle as a quick demo: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/3iiaab

P.S. The dropzone component [does not support file types](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dialog-components/#dropzone). But you can check the file types after they are uploaded.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer!

What I'm attempting to do is to replace the moxiemanager image / file upload with my own code.

I have successfully:

- added an 'upload' button to my custom file browser
- added the dropzone and uploaded images with a custom server script

Everything is working just dandy except the dropzone in my custom dialog, by default, only accepts images; I can't find the option to change it to files, which was essentially my original question, albeit badly worded...

I note the built-in dropzone allows files and images - how do I configure mine?

Comment: Having reviewed this again, the dropzone DOES allow files; it was my handling of the drop event that was only processing images. HOWEVER - the file input type is set to image/* and the dropzone renders with 'Drop an image here' and 'Browse for an image'. There must be an option to change this?

Comment: It isn't possible at the moment. But it may change in the future. You can track the progress in this issue: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/4903